# how to explode a string using a foreach

Tags: php

I got this string

```
$string = '1:23:health,2:24:mana';
$v = explode(",", $string);
foreach($v as $data)
{
    echo $data[0][1];
}
```

What im looking is to making a "multidimensional string" by exploding ','

Wanna do this:

```
data[0][0] = 1;
data[0][1] = 23;
data[0][2] = "health";
```

How can i do this in PHP?

Comment: `explode` again on `':'`…?!

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$string = '1:23:health,2:24:mana';

$result = [];
foreach (explode(',', $string) as $step) {
  $result[] = explode(':', $step);
}

print_r($result);
```

An alternative is:

```
$string = '1:23:health,2:24:mana';

$result = array_chunk(preg_split('/[:,]/', $string), 3);

print_r($result);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I actually tried a second explode but i guess my brain just ignored the fact it needed to be stored as an array